# How to get first element of a string in a list and the rest in the list?

Tags: python, list, file

String = "1 rest of string"

I want to get [1, "rest of string"] in a array

I want to do the python equivalent of nextint for the first part of the array and the rest of the line for the last part of the array

Comment: That's not a 2D array/list. It's a simple, 1D list.

Comment: `[int(String[0]), String[1:]]`, although this would also include the space between, which I don't know if that is desired or not. Maybe try `[int(String[0]), String[2:]]`

Comment: was going to do this for every line in a file, but I just need to know how to do it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for 2D array do this

```
string  = "1 rest of string"
element_1 = string[0]
rest = string[1:]
my_array = [[element_1],[rest]]
```

If you looking for two elements in one list, do the following

```
my_array = [element_1, rest]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 a = "1 rest of string"
 b = [a[0],a[1:]]
 print(b)
```

Comment: While the original question is significantly lacking in detail, you should probably assume that the initial number is not always single-digit.

Comment: Good point @jarmod, we need more test cases maybe. I think a `split` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
String = "12 rest of string"
first, rest = int(String.split()[0]), " ".join(String.split()[1:])
print([first, rest])
```

Output:

```
[12, 'rest of string']
```

Assuming your first part can contain numbers with more than one digit.